# Invalid type signature in recursive data constructor

Tags: haskell

So, following along with a sample code on [streams](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-01-08-streams-coroutines.md), this fails to be loaded into ghci:

```
data MyStream a = MyStream a (MyStream a)

intsFrom n :: MyStream Integer
intsFrom n = MyStream n $ intsFrom $ n + 1
```

Getting error:

```
stream.hs:3:1:
    Invalid type signature: intsFrom n :: MyStream Integer
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Update: If I just type `intsFrom :: MyStream Integer` I get error:

```
stream.hs:4:1:
    The equation(s) for `intsFrom' have one argument,
    but its type `MyStream Integer' has none
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry about the broken type signature. I've updated the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want your signature to be something like this:

```
intsFrom :: Integer -> MyStream Integer
```

`Integer` here is your argument, and `MyStream Integer` is the result of `intsFrom`.

Answer (score 4):

You should just use the function name in the line with the type signature, not add parameter names. So instead of

```
intsFrom n :: MyStream Integer
```

use

```
intsFrom :: MyStream Integer
```

You also have to make sure that the type you declare matches the function. Since the function takes an `Integer` parameter, the correct signature would be:

```
intsFrom :: Integer -> MyStream Integer
```